# How do I create a window in WPF waiting for files to be dropped in?

Tags: python, wpf

I would like to have a window which would stay on top on which I could drag files and these files will be FTP'ed somewhere.

I can handle the FTP part but I do not know how to use the WPF to make a window which would listen to drag and drop from files and get the paths of the files dropped.

EDIT: I am looking for the Python WPF version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the AllowDrop property of the window and handle the drop event. 
Refer below code.

```
<Window x:Class="ItemsControl_Learning.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControl_Learning"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Drop="Window_Drop" AllowDrop="True">

private void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {                
            string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First you need to set the property `AllowDrop` in the window.
2. Handle `DragEnter` and `Drop` events. In `DragEnter`, you can restrict the file types that your application will allow. In `Drop` event, you have to process the file.

If you want to restrict some file types then handle `DragEnter`, `DragOver` and `DragLeave` events as shown in the sample. All file types except `jpg` are allowed to be dropped.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DragDrop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        AllowDrop="True" Drop="Window_Drop" DragEnter="Window_DragEnter" DragOver="Window_DragEnter" DragLeave="Window_DragEnter">
    <Grid AllowDrop="True" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Name="TB" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System;

namespace DragDrop
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                TB.Text = filePaths[0];
            }

        }

        private void Window_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                if (filePaths != null)
                {
                    if (filePaths[0].Contains("jpg"))
                    {
                        // JPG is not supported
                        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```